# How to insert multiple data to a table with auto_increment primary key column?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

So I'm using SQLite 3.6 and tried to insert multiple data to my table which has 3 columns (1 AI PK) using

```
INSERT INTO 'tablename'
      SELECT 'data1' AS 'column1', 'data2' AS 'column2'
UNION SELECT 'data3', 'data4'
UNION SELECT 'data5', 'data6'
UNION SELECT 'data7', 'data8'
```

somehow it didn't work and I got this error

> table transport_type has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied

Is there any other way to input multiple data?

Comment: try inserting a null into the auto increment column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not providing data for all columns in a table, or the data you provide is not in the same order as the columns in the table, you must provide a list of column names:

```
INSERT INTO tablename(column1, column2)
SELECT ...
```

---

Related examples:

1. Omitting some columns to use their default value.

   Technically this is the same as above, but this demonstrates usage for non-auto-increment columns.

   ```
   INSERT INTO myTable(column1, column7, column21)
   SELECT 'one', 'seven', 'twenty-one';
   ```
2. Inserting columns in a different order than was defined.

   Given a table with the following definition:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE myTable (
       column1 VARCHAR(255),
       column2 VARCHAR(255),
       column3 VARCHAR(255),
       column4 VARCHAR(255)
   );
   ```

   We can specify a column list to insert rows where the data is given out of order. Note the columns are specified in a different order than the definition.

   ```
   INSERT INTO myTable(column3, column4, column2, column1)
   SELECT 'three', 'four', 'two', 'one';
   ```